# How to add Header with Authorization for springdoc-openapi endpoint calls

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

**Swagger2 (springfox) worked with:**

```
@Bean
public Docket getDocket() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(RestController.class))
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
        .paths(PathSelectors.any())
        .build()
        .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
        .globalOperationParameters(Collections.singletonList(getAuthHeader()));
}

private Parameter getAuthHeader() {
    return new ParameterBuilder()
        .parameterType("header")
        .name("Authorization")
        .modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))
        .defaultValue(getBase64EncodedCredentials())
        .build();
}

private String getBase64EncodedCredentials() {
    String auth = authUser.getUser() + ":" + authUser.getPassword();
    byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encode(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    return "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth, Charset.defaultCharset());
}
```

**Springdoc-openapi:**

```
@Bean
public OpenAPI getOpenAPI() {
    return new OpenAPI().components(new Components()
        .addHeaders("Authorization", new Header().description("Auth header").schema(new StringSchema()._default(getBase64EncodedCredentials()))));
}
```

I cant achieve it for springdoc-openapi. It seems the header is not working.

Comment: Did you figure this out. I have just integrated springdoc-openapi-ui into a spring boot app. But while it can display the swagger ui for all my endpoints, I have no option to add an authorization header to each request @akudama

Answer (score 12):

Adding parameter definition to a custom OpenAPI bean will not work because the parameter won't get propagated to the operations definitions. You can achieve your goal using OperationCustomizer:

```
@Bean
public OperationCustomizer customize() {
    return (operation, handlerMethod) -> operation.addParametersItem(
            new Parameter()
                    .in("header")
                    .required(true)
                    .description("myCustomHeader")
                    .name("myCustomHeader"));
}
```

The OperationCustomizer interface was introduced in the springdoc-openapi 1.2.22.

Answer (score 12):

For `Authorization` header to work, it is also required to have `security` in the root of the specification.

For example, below code would set JWT bearer token in the `Authorization` header.

```
@Bean
public OpenAPI customOpenAPI(@Value("${openapi.service.title}") String serviceTitle, @Value("${openapi.service.version}") String serviceVersion) {
    final String securitySchemeName = "bearerAuth";
    return new OpenAPI()
            .components(
                    new Components()
                            .addSecuritySchemes(securitySchemeName,
                                    new SecurityScheme()
                                            .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
                                            .scheme("bearer")
                                            .bearerFormat("JWT")
                            )
            )
            .security(List.of(new SecurityRequirement().addList(securitySchemeName)))
            .info(new Info().title(serviceTitle).version(serviceVersion));
}
```

Generated specification yml will be as below -

```
security:
  - bearerAuth: []
...
components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
```

So, based on above specification, below part leads to `Authorization` header

```
  security:
    - bearerAuth: []
```

Answer (score 10):

The behaviour you are describing is not related to springdoc-openapi. But to swagger-ui which respects the OpenAPI Spec as well:

- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5715

  The OpenAPI 3 specification **does not allow explicitly adding Authorization header**. For more information, please read:

  `Note: Header parameters named Accept, Content-Type and Authorization are not allowed. To describe these headers`

  Please read:
- https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#header-parameters.

Comment: okey, thanks bro